# how can i have a CheckBoxFor using int?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, custom-controls

I need help to build a CheckBoxFor for getting an `int` value.

Something like:

```
@Html.CheckBoxForInt(m => m.foo.intValue)
```

It should be **checked** if `intValue = 1` else **not checked**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you expose a bool property in your model that converts to/from the int?

Something like this:

```
public bool BoolValue
{
    get { return IntValue == 1; }
    set { IntValue = value ? 1 : 0;}
}

public int IntValue { get; set; }
```

Then you could use it to create the checkbox

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.foo.BoolValue)
```

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the response above gave me errors but based on the same idea I've change the code like this:

```
public int IntValue { get; set; }

public bool BoolValue
{
    get { return IntValue == 1; }
    set { 
            if(value)
                IntValue = 1;
            else
                IntValue = 0;
    }
}
```

and that work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the checkbox helper example for handling int values:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxIntFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, int>> expression, object htmlAttributes)        
    {
        // get the name of the property
        string[] propertyNameParts = expression.Body.ToString().Split('.');

        // create name and id for the control
        string controlId = String.Join("_", propertyNameParts.Skip(1));
        string controlName = String.Join(".", propertyNameParts.Skip(1));

        // get the value of the property
        Func<TModel, int> compiled = expression.Compile();
        int booleanSbyte = compiled(html.ViewData.Model);

        // convert it to a boolean
        bool isChecked = booleanSbyte == 1;

        // build input element
        TagBuilder checkbox = new TagBuilder("input");
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("id", controlId);
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("name", controlName);
        checkbox.MergeAttribute("type", "checkbox");

        if (isChecked)
        {
            checkbox.MergeAttribute("checked", "checked");
            checkbox.MergeAttribute("value", "1");
        }
        else
        {
            checkbox.MergeAttribute("value", "0");
        }
        SetStyle(checkbox, htmlAttributes);

        // script to handle changing selection
        string script = "<script>" +
                            "$('#" + controlId + "').change(function () { " +
                                "if ($('#" + controlId + "').is(':checked')) "+
                                    "$('#" + controlId + "').val('1'); " +
                                "else " +
                                    "$('#" + controlId + "').val('0'); " +
                            "}); " +
                        "</script>";

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(checkbox.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing) + script);
    }

    private static void SetStyle(TagBuilder control, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        if(htmlAttributes == null)
            return;

        // get htmlAttributes
        Type t = htmlAttributes.GetType();
        PropertyInfo classInfo = t.GetProperty("class");
        PropertyInfo styleInfo = t.GetProperty("style");
        string cssClasses = classInfo?.GetValue(htmlAttributes)?.ToString();
        string style = styleInfo?.GetValue(htmlAttributes)?.ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(style))
            control.MergeAttribute("style", style);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClasses))
            control.AddCssClass(cssClasses);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

my database needs to accept an int, and i want to have a checkbox that sends that int from my form in Razor. on the page i also use angularJS (also easy to just use pure JS). So here is a solution that does not involve changing models etc.

in form:

```
<input ng-click="checkCheckBox()" type="checkbox" id="myCheck">

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Role, new { id = "id_checkbox", Value = 0 })
```

in javascript:

```
$scope.checkCheckBox= function(){

   var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;

   if (x == true) { $('#id_checkbox').val(3);}
   else { $('#id_checkbox').val(0);}

}
```